# Sql Server Analysis Services Access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, user-permissions

I am able to make a new SSAS database but I am not able to do anything. E.g. can not add a Data Source, Data Source Views Dimensions etc.

When I right click Data Source or Data Source Views all I see is "Reports, Refresh"

I checked the version of sql server is 2008 R2. It is the Standard Edition x64.

I am part of the administrators group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [Business Intelligent Development Studio (BIDS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx) to create SSAS Dimensions and Cubes ([video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aED2Q9qntfY)).

Comment: I was looking at from SQL Server management studio. Than VS 2010, before I realized that I have to use VS 2008.